# Outlook Addin Installation and Deployment(userwise and machinewise)

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

We have developed a Outlook Add In.  I wish to deploy this add in in both Single User / Multi user environment

I have managed to deploy this Add In for single user environment. I am adding a Registry Entry (HKCU) for single user and the add in gets installed under "APPDATA\ROAMING\CompanyName\AddInName." I am using standard MSI for installation
But the issue I face is even if i ran the Installer, I don't see Add In appearing under Outlook, unless, I browse to the installation path (as above) and double click on VSTO file and deploy it again.

For Terminal Server / Citrix based implementation, I am trying to change the Registry to HKLM but not 100% sure how this will work.

My question is that
1. How I can have deploy this Outlook Add in only in one attempt. I don't want to install and  then deploy (double click VSTO) file?
2. How I can deploy this add in for Terminal Server / Citrix based implementation?

I have gone through various blogs but they are not very clear and cause more confusion.

Would appreciate your expert suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can only answer the first part of your question - You will have to create registry entries so that when Outlook is started it automatically applies your installed add in. See the link below for a detailed explanation of the registry keys that are required. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx

In short, You need to add a registry entry for your add in that contains a FriendlyName, Description, LoadBehavior and Manifest input. Directing to the following link will tell you exactly how to do this and exactly where to put the keys. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx#To-create-registry-keys

Best of luck and If you have any issues with that, comment below and I will help you as soon as I can.

**As an added note, I once had problems similar to the one you are having, and in my case it was due to the LoadBehavior setting. I was using the "UK Spelling" of the word instead of the US spelling. LoadBehavior must be specified exactly as I have written it here.